# How to delete this field after 5m automatically on mongoDB ? mongodb, mongoose ,schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this is my `schema` i want to automatically expire this field after 5 minutes. how i do that?

```
const userRegistrationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    mobile: {
        type: Number, trim: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true
    },
    // email Varification
    verified: {
        type: Boolean,
    },
    otp: {
        type: Number,
    },
    password: {
        type: String, trim: true,
    },
    confirmPassword: {
        type: String, trim: true,
    },
```

if user enter this value and otp store like this

```
mobile: 9561300851
email: "xyz@gmail.com"
verified: false
otp: 8236
```

and after 5 minutes i want to my data look like with otp field

```
mobile: 9561300851
email: "skcoder510@gmail.com"
verified: false
```

I hope I have explained my problem then how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB supports documents deletion only after a certain time using TTL. However for field deletion what you can do is after using the OTP you can remove the field using $unset.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/

Or, you can create scheduler which will run after certain time and remove all the used OTP field using $unset.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK MongoDB only supports TTL on documents, not on fields: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/

You could consider creating a separate OTP schema that has a TTL index of 5 minutes. The relevant Mongoose documentation can be found here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schemadateoptions_SchemaDateOptions-expires